# Terminal freezes after using tar or gz

Tags: bash, terminal, tar, gzip

On Linux within `bash` the Pseudo Terminal window (`terminator`) as well as the Terminal itself "freezes" when trying to use autocomplete (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) as well as after getting an error message using `gzip` and `tar`.

So far this only happens with `gzip` and `tar`…

- after getting an error message (own fault, typos, etc.)
- using autocomplete

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> somehow solves the problem in so far as I can work on and have (up to now) no problems with other commands EXCEPT `tar`. Thus, the problem is repeatable. I would very much appreciate help from here on.

I can isolate the problem further, as it had a "comback": As hinted [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152953/terminal-freezes-after-using-tar-or-gz#comment249864_152953), <strike>un</strike> commenting the following section in **`~/home/USER/.bashrc`**

```
# if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
# fi
```

helped in so far as *trying* to use autocomplete

- still sends the Terminal Emulation (`pts`) into deep freeze when using <kbd>TAB</kbd> after the first occurrence of `--` until <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> ends it
- the real terminal (`tty`) seems to ignore `TAB` completely with `gzip` and `tar`. I could live that and a long face, but then … really?

**Config Files**
The other config file (I know) for completion would be `/etc/bash.bashrc` which would turn completion off completely I guess. Not good. The config files for the terminal emulator doesn't have any settings for autocomplete or such

I can type some characters and then the Terminal freezes – takes no more keystrokes. This happens both in an emulated terminal window (`pts`) in the GUI and also "real" promt (`tty`).

I work from a keyboard connected via USB, and not on a laptop or the like.

What would be a proper way to kill a terminal session like: »kill `tty1` from `tty2`« because this is exactly what I'm stuck here!

Comment: I dunno what's going on there, but.. maybe `CTRL+Q`?

Comment: @mikeserv in the emulated or the real terminal? I can close the emulated (GUI) through a button (which still is quite annoying), but this doesn't help in the real thing (still stuck, only accepting the CMD+ALT+Fn salute)

Comment: @mikeserv CTRL+Q did nothing, CTRL+C helped - updated the question. BUT: "Don't use autocomplete with `tar`" can't be a solution… thanks anyway, you hinted into a direction where I found help (somehow).

Comment: Most probably it is completion problem and has nothing to do with terminal but with shell (bash/zsh/...). So tell which shell you use and show .bashrc or .zshrc.

Comment: Has the current working directory got many (hundreds, thousands, +) of files / directories in it?

Comment: @JoshuaMiller No, there are ~10 files, thus… But yes, I experienced this with such directories, correct! But then, I usually get asked something like "… really want to have all possibilites displayed?" - or sometimes I get the prompt back after a looooooooong listing :) But here, I don't get a prompt back or anything. Freezes, can only be quit with `ctrl+C` or closing the Pseudo Terminal Windon (GUI). And yes, I've literally waited hours, like an afternoon, half a workday etc. out of curiosity what might happen (result: Ice Age. Frozen.)

Comment: @JoshuaMiller Seems we've got an anser: So far commenting (thus deactivating) the corrsponding entries in `.bashrc` helped in that far as autocomplete doesn't freeze the (Pseudo) Terminal. Autocomplete doesn't seem to play nice with `tar` or `gzip` or the other way around.

Comment: Which entries in .bashrc?  (You can opt to answer your own question)

Comment: @JoshuaMiller updated the question and about answering my own question: I was thinking about, but as your hint helped the most at the moment I thought it was your term to get the reputation deserved ;)

Comment: What's the output of `ls -1a | wc -l` and it occurs with all files?

Comment: @Braiam I beg your pardon?

Comment: Edit your question and provide the output of `ls -la | wc -l`

Comment: @Braiam List (`ls` in long format `-l`, also hidden files `-a`) and count lines (`wc -l`) of what? Config files? Which one? Seriously, I really don't get it! (Are we - literally - on the same page / website / question here

Comment: The directory where you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16850/discussion-between-erch-and-braiam).

Comment: Can't log in to the chat, not with two different browsers and giving up after login plays ping pong with me and redirects me to I don't know where. I give up.

Comment: I get this issue in Ubuntu 14.04 but not in Amazon Linux, or Debian 8.  Anybody else?